# MIDI Keyboard controller and Windows Tablet

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I installed Mixcraft 7 on my iBall slide i701 and assigned all the VSTs I required for a particular song to different instrument tracks and pre-set the volume/pan of each. The plan was to select/touch any track to get the instrument set there activated. Next step was to connect my m-audio keystation 49 to the tab and there I failed since the tab seemed no way interested in recognizing the MIDI keyboard. What do I need to do in order to use that tab as my VST host?

I do not own an iPad as many suggested to use Garageband; nor do I get to buy a Surface tab as many video-people showed on YouTube. I don't think my Mi4i would be able to produce anything close to real-time (though I have not tested ALL the apps from the Google Play Store).

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [M-Audio claims it doesn't require drivers](http://m-audio.com/kb/article/1670#drivers).  I'd double-check that the USB ports and cable are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB devices on tablets are a tricky matter.

First make sure you're using the right cable adapter from the microUSB/OTG port in your tablet, to the standard USB host (female) connector. Have your tried the conection with other devices (e.g. a simple memory pen drive)? Does the MIDI controller give any sign of life when connected (e.g. LEDs lightinh or flashing)?

If the connection works with other USB devices but not the MIDI controller, or you see the controller respond in some way but not be properly recognized by the host, then you may have a power problem. The tablet may not be able to supply enough power to the controller. This is a common enough problem for example with external USB hard drives, which required more current debit than the USB port of a tablet normally supplies. I have seen devices start (LEDs light, etc.) but not work properly untill an external USB power supply with sufficent current yeld is provided.
If that's the case then it may be able to be solved by an OTG cable adapter with a Y connection to allow the simultaneous connection of the power supply.

On another line of inquiry, can you see the controller in Windows's Device Manager? Check the article indicated above by Mathew, and specially this link here http://m-audio.com/kb/article/1619, for some clues by the manufacturer.